# How to use Qt move two windows simultaneously?

Tags: qt

I was building a media player, and now I have two windows, one is the QMainWindow class SimplePlayer, which is my video window. The other one is the playlist, the QDialog class, and I want to implement dragging the video window, which is my SimplePlayer window, and at the same time my playlist can move with it, so what should I do?

For example: *Drag the left window, and the right window will follow.*
[image: application image]

Comment: To clarify... Is the dragging automated, or is it manual? Do you mean the `QDialog` should be anchored firmly to the right of the window?

Comment: yes,  the QDialog should be anchored firmly to the right of the window.

Comment: Is that you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50908396/qt-how-to-glue-two-windows-and-move-them-together/50908816#50908816